# Posting text fields containing url's

Tags: php, forms, url

I have a really confusing oddball. I have a form and I post a number of text fields and a text area. The problem I have is that on one or two of the fields I can post url's (for example, http://www.google.com).

The problam is that some of the fields work and other don't and just after the post of the form my site seems to stop working.

Below is the code.

```
  <form action="uploadbannerAction.php" method="post" id="addBanner" name="addBanner" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <table width="90%">

       <tr><td colspan="2"><hr /></td></tr>
       <tr>
           <td><label for="name">Name: </label></td>
           <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name" /></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr>
           <td><label for="file">Image: </label></td>
           <td><input type="file" name="file" id="file"></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr>
           <td><label for="extra">Text: </label></td>
           <td><input type="text" id="text" name="text" /></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr>
           <td><label for="link">Link: </label></td>
           <td><input type="text" id="link" name="link" /></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr>
           <td><label for="details">Details: </label></td>
           <td><textarea name="details" class="mceEditor"></textarea></td>
       </tr> 
       <tr>
           <td><label for="claim">Claim: </label></td>
           <td><input type="text" id="claim" name="claim" /></td>
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td><label for="priority">Priority: </label></td>
            <td><strong><i>Priority for a new entry is set to it's lowest. Please change once added if you need to be changed.</i></strong></td>
         </tr> 
         <tr>
             <td><label for="link">Offer Type: </label></td>
             <td>      
             <select name="adverttype" >
               <option value="" >Please Select...</option>
               <?php
                $rowSet = $db->selectAllNoLimit(adverttype);

                foreach($rowSet as $key => $offer){
                  echo "<option value=\"" . $offer['id'] . "\">" . $offer['type'] . "    </option>";
                }
                ?>
              </select>
              </td>
            </tr> 
            </table>

           <p class="submit"><button name="submit-banner" value="addBanner">Submit</button></p>
        </form>
```

And below is the code the form gets posted to:

```
 <?php
ob_start(); //This is needed for the header to work on the live site!!!!

require_once 'includes/global.inc.php';
include 'classes/advertClass.php'; //Include the Property Class

 if(isset($_POST))
 {  
 //Create a new object
 $advert = new advert(""); 

 //Collect the variables passed from POST
  $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['text']);
  $file = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['file']);
  $link = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['link']);
  $claim = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['claim']);
  $details = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['details']);
  $priority = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['priority']);
  $adverttype = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['adverttype']);

 //Put collected variables into an array called newsArray
 $advertArray = array('name'=>$name,'text'=>$text,'link'=>$link,'claim'=>$claim,'details'=>$details,'priority'=>$priority,'adverttype'=>$adverttype);
 $advert->save($advertArray);

 $error[] = "Thanks. The offer has been added";
 header("Location: bannerupload.php?e= $error[0]");
 }
 ?>
```

Now the problem I have is that when I post a url in the text field called link it works but when i try do the same on claim. It doesn't work and its kind of like the form and everything else on that page gets displayed without the css. I have also tried printing the $_POST variables straight after the form submission but when I have a url in the claim text field the print_r doesn't get actioned.

Im very confused. Your help would be very much appreciated. 
Regards

**UPDATE**
I am receiving the error message below.

Not Acceptable

An appropriate representation of the requested resource /admin/uploadbannerAction.php could not be found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Thanks 
Wayne

Comment: Look at the source(mostly the first lines) when your page displays "without the css".

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the quick reply.

Will upload the source code of the page going wrong

Comment: I have checked the source code and it's just showing the page contents for some reason.

Comment: we are almost there, http://jsfiddle.net/ just put all your code to the html field and paste here the given url.

Comment: I have added the form to the html section. Not sure if I need to add anything else. Please bear with me as I'm new to this. 

http://jsfiddle.net/2BA53/

Comment: np, I requested the complete output from the "messed up page", because what you shown after the question update has a bit too much html tag and doctype, metas with different properties and different places. would you change it in the fiddle?

Comment: Ah ok. That's done now. 

http://jsfiddle.net/2BA53/1/ 

Also, if this helps.I'm getting a 406 error.

Answer (score 0):

1)  <strike>$file = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['file']);</strike>

use $_FILE  super global variable

2) priority in not defined anywhere any text box or nothing is there please check it ..you are using normal text

Comment: Hello. I have tried the changes you recommended and it' still happening

Answer (score 0):

I checked the output, the incorrect page shown may caused by that first 23 lines (you should correct that if its generated even if the save working as intended).

> This function will turn output buffering on. While output buffering is
>   active no output is sent from the script (other than headers), instead
>   the output is stored in an internal buffer. [php.net ob_start function description](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)

Just after the

```
$advert->save($advertArray);
```

add this few lines and see what happens:

```
$op = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
die($op);
```

Comment: Thank's for the suggestion. Just tried it and it's not getting that far. It's strange how one text field can post url's but the other causes problems.

Comment: It still wouldn't work as when the problems occurs it doesn't even allow me to print_r() the $_POST results.